# Image edge/shape detection in OpenCV

Tags: image-processing, opencv

After converting a color image to black and white, I want to detect the shape of the image. 
What are the best methods to detect the shape? I mean how can I detect it pixel wise or histogram wise? And how can I store each detected shape in a database if it's like histogram

eg:

[image]

To detect above image shape what method is most accurate?

And I saw same kind of method on the internet after convert image to binary they store same kind of graph information(below link) in here how we store information like that?

[image]

Comment: This is a broad open-ended question. Shape detection and contour detection are extensive topics. You might get more responses if you are more specific.

Comment: If you want store the shapes you could use contouring and store the contour points list in a database.

Comment: and if you want the histogram there is a structure called cvHistogram in opencv and lot of functions to work with it

Answer (score 1):

Try coding shape with strings. It could be done with Freeman chain code or angle chain code(approx contour with approxPolyDP() then code segments with angle and length). 
For matching Freeman chain code you could use pairwise geometrical histogram for example.

Answer (score 0):

[**A Survey of Shape Feature Extraction**](http://www.intechopen.com/source/pdfs/5781/InTech-A_survey_of_shape_feature_extraction_techniques.pdf) is link to all the existing methods for shape Feature Extractions..

Hi, if the link not working then  try this paper in Google

> "A Survey of Shape Feature Extraction Techniques by *Yang
>   Mingqiang,Kpalma Kidiyo1 and Ronsin Joseph*"

Hope it is useful, 
Have a Happy coding...